# How to calculate specific rows in layer field- ArcGIS 10.3

Tags: arcgis-10.3, field-calculator, table-of-contents

I try to calculate specific rows (OBJECTID 23-29) in "field_name" field with field calculator- i try to fill in the value "rt8". This is the attribute table:

[image]

but i can't find any option to calculate specific rows in it- i can calculate for the whole filed-and that isn't what i'm seeking. I must mention that i want to calculate without selecting features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field calculator works always for the selection of rows, or if there are none selected for all rows. Just select the rows you want to be calculated by clicking the grey squares left of the first column (use shift or strg for multiple selection) or with "select by attributes".